# Getting entropy of image in python / scikit image?

Tags: python, image, matlab, scikit-image

I note that Matlab has a [straightforward function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html) for getting the entropy of an image. I need something similar for python. [Scikit image has an entropy filter](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html#skimage.filters.rank.entropy), which outputs the image using the least amount of bits needed to do so (at least, I think it does). I assume that to do this it calculates the entropy, but I can't seem to access it as a scalar value.

Before I code a function to do this manually, does anyone know if already exists and I'm somehow missing it? Or for that matter, some existing code that they'd recommend?

Comment: Calculating the entropy of an image is quite straightforward. You find the histogram of the image, normalize the histogram so that it becomes a PDF, then use the standard entropy equation to calculate the entropy.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind shelling out to **ImageMagick** you can do it like this:

```
convert someImage.png -format '%[entropy]' info:
0.907238
```

Not sure how you do it with the **ImageMagick** Python bindings, but it is probably possible.